# Removing unwanted special (`*`, `"` etc.) and HTML (`<a8>` etc.) characters in R

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I'm getting the responses to a survey (which is a data.frame) but the responses included several unwanted special (`*`, `"` etc.) and HTML (`<a8>` etc.) characters such as the one show below.

I was wondering if there might be a way to remove these unwanted characters from `Input` to achieve my `Desired_output`?

```
Input = "<a8>""""If you do not participate in any school or community activities or clubs, please describe why. (If you do not want to respond to this item, type """"""""skip"""""""".)""""<a8>"

Desired_output = "If you do not participate in any school or community activities or clubs, please describe why. (If you do not want to respond to this item, type "skip".)"
```

Comment: Why `"skip"` in desired output ? Are quotes unwanted ?

Comment: @sln, well, that is what originally included in the survey question. I should have mentioned that. Good catch:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(output <- gsub('"+', '"', gsub('<[^>]+>', "", input)))
[1] "\"If you do not participate in any school or community activities or clubs, please describe why. (If you do not want to respond to this item, type \"skip\".)\""
```

To view the results as expected, we just use `cat`:

```
cat(output)
"If you do not participate in any school or community activities or clubs, please describe why. (If you do not want to respond to this item, type "skip".)"
```